# get next auto increment value from an empty table

Tags: mysql

I've got a table named 'messages'

I flooded it with approx 150 tables I'm not sure about the count. The 'id' field is 'primary' and 'auto_increment'.

by mistake i deleted all the records in the table (NOTE: I did not truncate the table so the count would not be reset) and I lost the count of the number of records.

Is there a possibility that I can get the next count of 'id' field? This is causing problems for me while trying to insert a new message using ajax message.

Comment: No, the counter will be resetted by truncation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c03e5d/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did **not** truncate the table then you can use

```
select auto_increment 
from information_schema.TABLES 
where TABLE_NAME ='messages' and TABLE_SCHEMA='database_name'
```

to get the next auto-increment value.

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5273e/1)

Comment: Perfect! This is feasible on localhost but when my app is hosted online will I have access to Information_Schema database?

Comment: Hard to tell. I guess you will.

Comment: Now this is a problem again. I'm not able to connect to information schema DB on my shared hosting with the following credentials, 'root' and ''. I think i need to copy the last id+1 to a separate table to gain access to next auto_increment value :(

Answer (score 1):

You could try a query like this to get the next ID:

```
SELECT id+1 AS next_id FROM your_table_name_here ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

You should probably not be inserting the ID into the table if it has auto-increment, however. You can give "NULL" as the ID value and it will fill in automatically.